# Can't connect to external Kafka Service from Istio Mesh

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, istio

I can't connect to an "external" (outside the mesh) Kafka service from inside the mesh. Inside the Istio mesh I have an Spring Boot app, which should connect to an platform Kafka service.

The Kafka service is reachable via an DNS name (I tried it, it is possible). To access the service I created an ServiceEntry with the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - kafka-service.foo.baa
  ports:
  - number: 37000
    name: tls-6
    protocol: tls
  - number: 36200
    name: tls-5
    protocol: tls
  - number: 36201
    name: tls-4
    protocol: tls
  - number: 36202
    name: tls-3
    protocol: tls
  - number: 36203
    name: tls-2
    protocol: tls
  - number: 36204
    name: tls-1
    protocol: tls
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

Sometime I get an connection, but sometime not and I don't know the issue and why it's working sometime.

These are some error message:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
```

```
Removing server kafka-service.foo.baa:37000 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka-service.foo.baa
```

I also tried to use this anntotation `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: 37000,36200,36201,36202,36203,36204,36205` to bypass the traffic, but this is not working as well.
The Bypass is only working, if I use the IP address instread of the DNS name as bootstrap server.

Please kindly help.

Comment: Hi, Do you have destination rule with traffic policy like [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings)?

Comment: So far, I haven't tried it with an DestinationService for the ServiceEntry. Is it necessary for egress traffic in general?